# Communicate between two differences @NGRX stores in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I created a project using Angular 14 and @NGRX. In my project has a feature called drag and drop.

The drag value exists in one component and drop that value into another component. These components are loaded from two different URLs. Therefore, I have two different stores.

The store of drag window has a value and the drop window needs to access that value exist in drag window. But, when I try get the value, the selector always checks in drop window store.

Are there any method to access or communicate between that kind of two different stores. Please help me to resolve this issue.[image]

Comment: It is not possible, since each store is unique per tab. You would need to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API or utilize the browsers localstorage

Comment: you should just use drag and drop api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API then take the data and insert it into an action that you dispatch and will then update the store

Comment: @IdontwearString Thanks for the response and will check with that way.

Comment: @Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen Thanks for the response. The value is stored before the drag and drop. That value is needed to access after the drop.

Comment: yeah but store the data on drag start into the drag event, so when drag drop it can fit perfectly into a action. that will then be stored in the other view. Don't bother trying to sync 2 tabs stores. it will be a messy thing.

Comment: @Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen thanks for the response. Will try with your solution.